# Is if statement order check fr object depend on compiler?

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement

Quick question. How the following code will perform order of check :

```
if ((NULL != ObjectPtr) && (ObjectPtr->isValid()) )
{
}
```

Is the order on `if`-statement depend on compiler used? Could that code crash if `ObjectPtr` is `NULL`?

Comment: Too many parentheses. <g>

Comment: [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) were relevant to C++ 20 years ago but that's no longer the case.

Comment: This is an obvious duplicate, come on 120k and 200k users.

Comment: @meagar: You can't blame anyone for not finding that question, its title is 100% wrong (now fixed).

Answer (score 3):

> Is the order depend on `if` statement depend on compiler used?

No.

> Could that code crash if `ObjectPtr` is `NULL`?

No.

The language guarantees that.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, the `&&` operator is guaranteed to be **short-circuiting**.  This means that the left-hand operand is checked first, and if it is false, none of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

So your code is safe and will not perform member access through the NULL pointer.

Similarly, `||` is also short-circuiting and will not evaluate any of its right-hand operand if the left operand is true.

With boolean operands, the bitwise operators `&` and `|` give the same result as the logical operators `&&` and `||`, but the bitwise operators do not short-circuit and their right-hand operand is always evaluated (possibly before the left-hand one).

Also as Quentin mentions in a comment, user-provided overloads of these operators do not short-circuit, because they are actually function calls and have the evaluation order of function calls (all arguments evaluated before the call).

Comment: Note: this only works with the built-in operators (which may or may not be obvious).